# Groupby Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

You guys are ruthless, makes a new programmer like me feel real welcome. :)

Alright let me try this one more time if I can correctly explain my situation. Like one of answer below I have a string that contains the following information. This was created using a while loop where each line ends with an Environment.Newline (There is no mistake in the first line, there is actually a blank line).

```
var s = @"
ABC-123, 80000, 1400 
ABC-123, 70000, 1250 
ABC-123, 65000, 1200 
BCD-234, 90000, 1300
BCD-234, 95000, 1100
XYZ-111, 24000, 1000
XYZ-111, 24000, 1000"
```

I originally asked if there is a way to group by the first column ie. all ABC-123 are grouped together, the second is summed and the third column is averaged. Please ignore the sum and average, I just need to understand how to group first.

Here's where I get confused, by using this statement for one of the answers below:

```
var ss = s.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(x => x.Split(", ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                .GroupBy(y => y[0]);
```

I understand what the answer is trying to do but I need help writing the result back into a string (maybe that's not the right choice, I don't know, always open to suggestions)so that I can use StreamWriter to save the result as a csv.

I've tried to understand IEnumerables but all the videos/websites just confuse the hell out of me. I've also tried outputting the results of ss so that maybe if I got a visual representation, then I could rewrite it but when I do I get the following results:

```
        Console.WriteLine(ss);
        Console.Read();
```

System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3[<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Char],System.Char,<

> f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Char]]

The output I would want would be a string that looked like this.

```
output = "ABC-123, 215000, 1283
BCD-234, 185000, 1200
XYZ-111, 48000, 1000"
```

Comment: Why not split it first and put in a table or some other object?

Comment: What column. This is a string. Strings don't have columns

Comment: What do you mean by "a string that outputs as"? A single string, or is that multiple strings? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, there is a way for that.

Comment: Is there a line break after every third value or is this one big string with a missing comma after every third value?

Comment: There is a line break after every line. Basically I tried 

    var table =    File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)
    .Select(record => record.Split(','))
    .Where(cell => cell.Length >= 2) // Add filter clause here
    .Select(cell => new { AFPCode = cell[10] }) 
    .GroupBy(x => x.AFPCode);

Comment: @user3813607 Please add that code to your question so it can be formatted properly.

Comment: Of course, if you just do `IEnumerable<T>.ToString()` you will get something like the mentioned above. There is no magic in .NET that will be able to printout well-formatted content of any object. You have to code that for yourself. What do you want to do with the grouping? Show us your expected result, or we can't help you.

Comment: I've revamped my original question. Hope you guys can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your inputdata is one long string:

```
var s = @"ABC-123, 80000, 1400 
        ABC-123, 70000, 1250 
        ABC-123, 65000, 1200 
        BCD-234, 90000, 1300
        BCD-234, 95000, 1100
        XYZ-111, 24000, 1000
        XYZ-111, 24000, 1000";

var ss = s.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)  //split by newlines
           .Select(x => x.Split(", ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) //Split each line by ,
           .GroupBy(y => y[0]); //group by first element of array
```

If it is an array of string already, you can ignore the first split by newlines

EDIT: Well, we cannot explain the theory behind IEnumerable, LINQ and grouping here. There are plenty of excellent tutorials on that. Maybe you should learn some basics first before jumping into such stuff.

But for your particular problem this should do it:

```
var lines = ss.Select(z => new {cKey = z.Key,
                            c2sum = z.Select(a=> Convert.ToInt32(a[1])).Sum(),
                            c3avg = z.Select(a=> Convert.ToInt32(a[2])).Average()});
foreach (var l in lines)
     Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", l.cKey, l.c2sum, l.c3avg);  //or whatever stream you want to write to
```

Comment: When you do this, the output generates System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable'3[System.String[],System.String,System.String[]]

Comment: Yes it certainly does that. You cannot just use `ss.ToString()` or `Console.WriteLine(ss)`. This is just the 'grouping by first column' as you asked for. You have to do some furthermore processing of the result. But as you didn't tell us your desired result, we are not able to do that.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear instructions, how would you output this as readable text (ultimately, I need this to write to a csv file)? I tried using a foreach loop but I don't think I'm heading in the right direction.

Comment: What is "readable text"? Why is your initial text not readable? You could perfectly write that string into a csv file. Give us an example, how the text should look like.

Comment: The reason why I have "var s" in your example as a string is because ultimately, I wanted the use StreamWriter and save the string as a csv after I used LINQ to group the first column together. As you can tell, I'm new to coding and don't understand why you can't just use StreamWriter.Writeline(ss) (I know that's not to code but trying to explain) to write the query into the file.

Comment: Once again: What is your desired output? The original string? Some calculations within in the group? If you want our help you have to show us the *exact output* you want to have!

Comment: I posted this in the original question but the output I would want would be a string that looked like this using LINQ

output = "ABC-123, 215000, 1283
BCD-234, 185000, 1200
XYZ-111, 48000, 1000"

Comment: I think I'm headed in the right direction thanks to you. Thank you so much for all your help today.

Comment: You're welcome. (And you're also welcome to accept and/or upvote the answer if it helped you)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your output is an array of strings, one way would be to split the strings by commas and group by the first result:

```
list.Select(s => s.Split(','))
    .GroupBy(a => a[0])
```

Note that the output will be an `IEnumerable<string[]>` - if you want the original string just keep it in the original select:

```
list.Select(s => new {S = s, Parts = s.Split(',')})
    .GroupBy(a => a.Parts[0])
    .Select(g => new {Key = g.Key, lines = g.Select(a => a.S) } );
```

Comment: Sorry if i am wrong but just curious how this is going to work. Each line in the above text represents a row and expected output is to group the entire row. With this logic we will have array of 21 elements rather than 7 :)